# Clear all data flushed to stdout in C

Tags: c, console, output, stdout

My program needs to dynamically update what was outputted to the console. How can I do this?

The outputted number of lines can vary, so `\r` tricks won't be easy to implement.

There is `__fpurge` in Linux, but it clears only buffered data that wasn't flushed.

Comment: `system("clear")` ?

Comment: There's no OS-independent way to do this in C. It's `clear` on Unix, `cls` on Windows.

Comment: If you want to do full-screen output, use the `ncurses` library, I think it has been ported to Windows.

Comment: `system("clear")` clears the entire screen. I need to clear only my program's `stdout`

Comment: Once the data is in the console, it does not belong to your program anymore, but to the console. So it might allow or disallow clearing it. I doubt the standard terminals distinguish between past outputs of different processes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe in the console there is some reference to the process or to the latest command, so I can call some function to do this. That's why i asked in the first place

Comment: Use a buffer for the screen in your code, , or try _curses_ now _ncurses_

Comment: @EugeneSh. actually there must be such interaction between console and program over `stdout` fd, since '\r' lets you overwrite the output

Comment: No, @OstapShyika, there does not need to be.  Sending a `\r` just changes (maybe) the position at which the next character successfully sent to the terminal *by any program* will be displayed.  That's not process specific.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Then I can change the position to the very start of what's outputted by the process

Comment: Maybe, @OstapShyika, if you keep careful enough track of what has been output.  And you'll need more than `\r` for that because there may be more than one line of output.

Comment: Terminals, including those serving as consoles, do not generally have any sense at all of the provenance of the data in their display memory.  They do not know about processes, including shells, or (shell) commands.  There is no sense of display data belonging to anything other than the terminal itself.  Terminal *drivers* have a sense of which processes are allowed to send data to the terminal at any given time, but these do not normally track data that have already been sent.

Comment: @Ostap I'd expect `fflush(stdout)` or `fflush(0)` to meet your goals.